# What is the risk of installing Facebook Video Calling jar file?

Tags: privacy, java, facebook

I'm trying to talk with somebody on Facebook, but after many Facebook privacy scandals, it's a big question.

Secondly on OSX, it's giving me the error that “FacebookVideoCalling_v1.6.jar” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.

If I install that software, is there any possibility that somebody can use/hack my microphone or video/camera through that application without my knowledge?

Comment: You need to define 'safe'. Safe from what? From Facebook listening in? From external parties listening in? Did you get this file from an official source? You can see that from our perspective, you've asked the equivalent of "I found a random file, is it safe to use?"

Comment: Changed to 'What is the risk', or if you've any better suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a JAR file is a *Java Runtime* file, it runs a java-based program.

What is common with OSX is that it checks the author fingerprint, and would give warnings if the Application or file isn't "trusted", which can mean its not gained through the Appstore, or is not signed (applications can be signed by an author).

JAR Files if I'm right, cannot be signed, thats why OSX gives an error.

Is it safe to install? if it's the official download from Facebook itself, it is, since they don't have school dropouts working on their security, you can safely assume the application is safe, as long as you do regular updates of course.

If you downloaded the JAR from any other site then Facebook, then i wouldn't really recommend it.

Any alternative for video/voice calling is Skype, or the Skype web app on [Outlook](http://www.outlook.com).

Comment: This doesn't really address the risks of using this software.  If we assume it is from Facebook directly, hasn't been modified in transit and is totally secure from outside influence, this still leaves the possibility that FB itself is reading/logging the chats/metadata/something.  In reality, the three things I assumed can't be taken for granted.  FB's engineers are people too and can make mistakes.

Comment: thats why i always advise to update regulary, to minimize known exploits used against you, because known exploits get fixed atleast, thats the idea)

Comment: It's Facebook, so you can bet that they collect as much information from your video chats as technically feasible. Collecting private information is the reason Facebook exists. They likely send all your video chats through voice recognition and log the keywords to further enhance your profile, just like they do with all of your communication via their platform.

Comment: information has $ tags written all over it, i never adressed the privacy "issue" because we all should know once you start up and start browsing, every site you visit is either being logged by Google or (insert random big company here), same goes for facebook *obviously*